# access to an object member passed by unique_ptr

Tags: c++, object, binary-search-tree, move, unique-ptr

I wrote the following code to check if a node is in the BST:

```
bool BST_Node :: BST_Find(unique_ptr<BST_Node> root, int key){ 
    if(!root || root->key == INT_MIN) return false;
    if(root->key == key) return true;
    else if(key < root->key) BST_Find(move(root->left), key);
    else BST_Find(move(root->right), key);
}
```

**root** parameter is passed using `move(bst)` where **bst** in an unique_ptr.
The problem is when it tries to read `root->key`: even if the key is present in the tree, this method returns false.
I've tried to use the debugger and **root** can not be accessed.

Here is the code that uses this method:

```
auto bst = make_unique<BST_Node>();
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    key = rand();
    if(!bst->BST_Find(move(bst), key)) {
        bst->BST_Insert(move(bst), key, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: When you pass a `std::unique_ptr` by value you pass the ownership. Obviously you should not do it here so change parameter type.

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: @Slava Explaining why: at the end of the method, the `std::unique_ptr` is destroyed. This also destroys the entire tree. You don't want a read-only operation like finding an element to delete your entire data structure.

Comment: Oh, I understand. What do you think is better to use? I'm trying to use unique_ptr because I want the memory free when the **for** terminetes.

Comment: @Daniele974 The answer given shows how to combine that goal (using `std::unique_ptr`  to easily manage memory) with this function (which shouldn't perform any memory management).

Comment: It is fine to use `std::unique_ptr` to properly manage object lifetime. Incorrect is to pass ownership to a function you are not suppose to. One of the way is to pass raw pointer to them, or as @Andrey suggested to pass a const reference to `std::unique_ptr`. Again having `BST_Find` parameter `std::unique_ptr` by value means when you call it you give up membership to that function.

Comment: Thanks you all! I fixed the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
bool BST_Node :: BST_Find(unique_ptr<BST_Node> const &root, int key){ 
    if(!root || root->key == INT_MIN) return false;
    if(root->key == key) return true;
    else if(key < root->key) return BST_Find(root->left, key);
    else return BST_Find(root->right, key);
} 

BST_Find(bst, 42) // no move
```

Comment: It generates the error: [Error] prototype for 'void BST_Node::BST_Find(const std::unique_ptr<BST_Node>&, int)' does not match any in class 'BST_Node'

Comment: @Daniele974 You have to change the parameter type in the original declaration of the function, too. Presumably that's in a header file.

Comment: Change signature of BST_Find method in class declaration in .h file to this bool BST_Find(unique_ptr<BST_Node> const &root, int key)

Comment: You should add explanation on what is OP problem and why this solves it. Answer as it is is very low quality.